# Grouping values in dataframe column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Type
   A
   A  
   A
   B
   B
   A
   B
```

Expected Output:

```
Type     Count
   A         3
   B         2
   A         1
   B         1
```

The code I have tried until now

```
result_list = list(df['Type'])
result_count = Counter(result_list)
result_dict = dict(result_count)
result_df = DataFrame(list(result_dict.items()),columns = ['Type','Count'])
```

The Output I am getting

```
Type       Count
   A           4
   B           3
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you need to define another column that will group parts of `AB` rows into group, then use `groupby` on each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
g = df.Type.ne(df.Type.shift())
count = df.Type.groupby(g.cumsum()).size()
df[g].assign(count=count.values).reset_index(drop=True)

    Type  count
0    A      3
1    B      2
2    A      1
3    B      1
```